# Python timestamps with time()

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have a few timestamps in a database that I would like to trim down to only about 10 timestamps, from most latest to oldest. All the timestamps in the DB were made using time() in python.

**Create timestamp:**

```
_timestamp = time.time()
```

**Timestamps:**

```
1435652632.92778
1435652633.01
1435652633.07
1435652633.13
1435652642.71371
1435652642.77
1435652675.13
1435652675.22
1435652717.74
1435652735.11
1435652735.16
1435652735.24
```

How can I ask python to remove the oldest timestamp?

I currently convert the timestamp to readable format using the below string in my script.

```
print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1434615010.27858)
>>2015-06-18 08:10:10.278580
```

I have no code yet to remove the oldest timestamps, however I would appreciate some help with this please.

Comment: What kind of database is it? You can almost certainly ask the *database* to remove rows outside the top 10. See [Delete all but top n from database table in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/46385)

Comment: The timestamps are all in one column of a row, separated by "-".

Comment: So they are all in a string? Then just split, convert to floats, sort and keep only the 10 highest. Or even use `heapq.nlargest()` if you want to do it with the most efficient method available.

Comment: `datetime.datetime()` objects are also sortable, so if you already have them converted like that just sort, take the first 10, etc.

Comment: correct they are all string format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an epoch timestamp which is simply seconds passed since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

In you case, sort the timestmaps and take the 10 top elements.

```
timestmaps = [1435652632.92778, 1435652633.01, 1435652633.07]
timestmaps.sort(reverse=True)
latestTimestamps = timestmaps[:10]
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters touché :)

Comment: You should use `reverse=True`, to keep the latest timestamps. Is there any reason not to use `heapq.nlargest(10, timestamps)` here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's what you want, but you can do this:

```
timestamps = [1435652632.92778,1435652633.01,1435652633.07,1435652633.13,1435652642.71371,1435652642.77,1435652675.13,1435652675.22,1435652717.74,1435652735.11,1435652735.16,1435652735.24]
timestamps.remove(min(timestamps)) #Remove the minimum value from the list
```