# Loop through each ID with more than 3 records in the same table

Tags: mysql

This is my table:

```
placeID | name | time
```

My goal is to remove the oldest records if the placeID has more than 3 record in the table.

It's pretty hard to understand, so example will make it clear:

```
1 | "Some Name" | *fresher timestamp*
1 | "Some Name" | *fresher timestamp*
1 | "Some Name" | *older timestamp* -- > Delete this result since there are more than 3 records, and this is the older than the rest
1 | "Some Name" | *older timestamp* -- > Delete this result since there are more than 3 records, and this is older than the rest
1 | "Some Name" | *fresher timestamp*
2 | "Some Name" | *fresher timestamp*
2 | "Some Name" | *fresher timestamp*
```

**My trouble:** How do I loop for each placeID that has more than 3 record in my table?

Removing the oldest results will not be a problem.

What I tried:

```
SELECT placeID,COUNT(placeID) FROM place_fbStatus WHERE count(placeID) > 3
```

**Error: #1111 - Invalid use of group function**

Another Try:

```
SELECT id, placeID
FROM place_fbStatus
HAVING COUNT( placeID ) >4
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

**Problem:** Show only one placeID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here my Answer:

First thing is to create a PRIMARY KEY on your Table. So it is easy to DELETE a ROW with this.

**Create the Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `placeID` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `placeID` (`placeID`,`time`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Insert some stuff:**

```
INSERT INTO `mytable` (`id`, `placeID`, `name`, `time`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Some Name', '2015-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (2, 1, 'Some Name', '2015-01-02 00:00:00'),
    (3, 1, 'Some Name', '2015-01-10 00:00:00'),
    (4, 1, 'Some Name', '2015-01-09 00:00:00'),
    (5, 2, 'Some Name', '2015-02-01 00:00:00'),
    (6, 2, 'Some Name', '2015-01-30 00:00:00'),
    (7, 1, 'Some Name', '2015-01-08 00:00:00');
```

**i add rid ( ROW ID per Place ) and the Rows are in the right order**

```
SELECT @rid:=IF( @pid = m.placeID, @rid+1 , 1) rid, m.*, @pid:=m.placeID AS pid
      FROM mytable m, (SELECT @rid:=0, @pid:=-1) AS tmp 
      ORDER BY placeID,TIME ASC
```

**And at last the Query to DELETE the ROWs:**

```
DELETE mt FROM mytable mt
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT @rid:=IF( @pid = m.placeID, @rid+1 , 1) rid, m.*, @pid:=m.placeID AS pid
      FROM mytable m, (SELECT @rid:=0, @pid:=-1) AS tmp 
      ORDER BY placeID,TIME ASC
  ) AS x
  WHERE x.rid >3
) AS dt ON mt.id = dt.id ;
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with rid, but I tried it - and it doesn't delete any records. x.rid shouldn't be x.pid?

Comment: can you post some data here or better do it on http://sqlfiddle.com/ . Post the CREATE table please

Comment: You said that you have a TIMESTAMP but there is a VARCHAR Field. Plese show the Values in it and try my hole sample ( Create, Insert and Delete STatement)

Comment: I'm sorry. It's UNIX timestamp. (Example: 1442082119). I didn't think it's matter. I store it as varchar. I think your query should work in both cases but it's not

Comment: yes its ok, but a cant find any error. i have testet it again. Can you please also post your modified Delete Query

Comment: Soory, i have insert his in your Table and the DELETE works. it deletes 2 ROWS  -  
INSERT INTO `place_fbStatus` (`id`, `placeID`, `objID`, `theTime`)
VALUES
 (1, 1, 'Some Name', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01 00:00:00')),
 (2, 1, 'Some Name', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-02 00:00:00')),
 (3, 1, 'Some Name', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-10 00:00:00')),
 (4, 1, 'Some Name', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-09 00:00:00')),
 (5, 2, 'Some Name', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-02-01 00:00:00')),
 (6, 2, 'Some Name', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-30 00:00:00')),
 (7, 1, 'Some Name', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-08 00:00:00'));

Comment: No way.. I inserted the SAME rows using your insert query and it doesn't delete them...

Comment: i dont now why. what says select version();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89480/discussion-between-bernd-buffen-and-eliran).

Answer (score 0):

You almost nailed it. What you need is to combine GROUP BY and HAVING

```
SELECT placeID, count(placeID) AS cnt
  FROM place_fbStatus 
  GROUP BY placeID HAVING cnt>3
```

Comment: When I add `ORDER BY theTime ASC` or `ORDER BY theTime DESC` in both cases it shows the freshest record instaed of the oldest..

Comment: Your question was: "How do I loop for each placeID that has more than 3 record in my table?" If you need also to delete older records, you can go for @berndbuffen's solution, it's overcomplicated but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 3 ID FROM Table)
```

Refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46385/delete-all-but-top-n-from-database-table-in-sql)

Although, it seems after trying it myself, it seems some versions of mysql dont yet support limit clauses in subqueries (This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'). To workaround this, try using an alternate subquery that doesnt involve limits.