# MySQL - Efficiently delete all records except last N

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I started learning SQL recently and now was asked to perform a simple deletion on a table, keeping the last 100 records for each user. I was researching the best approach (more efficient way) to archive this, and found some possible solutions ([SQL query: Delete all records from the table except latest N?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578867/sql-query-delete-all-records-from-the-table-except-latest-n) , [Delete all but top n from database table in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46385/delete-all-but-top-n-from-database-table-in-sql)), but it is kind intricate for me to choose one based on efficiency. So I am here to ask for your help.

Here is the table called "access" where we keep users access log.

```
access:
- id (autoincrement) - primary
- userid (integer 11) - key
- refer (varchar 100)
- date (date/time)
```

My idea is to delete old records from the userid everytime this same user enter the system, just before inserting the new log.

I have tried this code bellow but got error: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

```
DELETE FROM
  access
WHERE
  id NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM access WHERE userid = 10 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100
  );
```

Please, can you suggest me some solution? Thanks!

Comment: do you store timestamp in any column which records time at which record was inserted. If you have done so you could use this timestamp value to delete past records.

Comment: I really wouldn't use MyISAM. Data integrity is far more important than sequential ids.

Comment: Sorry about delay, I posted this question 2 am in my time... @srikanthr, I have the id that is autoincrement, so I think that would be easier to rely on it instead of date/time fields...

Comment: @Strawberry, the engine is InnoDB, but as I said I just started with MySQL, so please give more information about your comment, I didn't understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try DELETE JOIN:

```
delete a from access a left join (
    select id
    from access
    order by id desc limit 1000
) b on a.id = b.id
where b.id is null;
```

If you want to keep top 1000 records of a given user (say 123) from deleting :

```
delete a from access a left join (
    select id
    from access
    where userid = 123
    order by id desc limit 1000
) b on a.id = b.id
where b.id is null;
```

If you want to delete rows only for user 123 except the top 1000 for that user:

```
delete a from access a left join (
    select id
    from access
    where userid = 123
    order by id desc limit 1000
) b on a.id = b.id
where b.id is null
and a.userid = 123;
```

Comment: GurV, your solution is not filtering by userid and I have no idea where to implement it... Please, can you update your answer? Thanks

Comment: Thank you! I will make tests... Please, what you think about this approach: "DELETE FROM access WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM access WHERE userid = 10 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100) foo) AND userid = 10;" I found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578867/sql-query-delete-all-records-from-the-table-except-latest-n ?

Comment: It's will do the same thing as my last query. And is hack, not a standard way.

Comment: Ok, this is what I wanted to know. Thanks!

Comment: Please, one last question... Why you used: "where b.id is null" ?

Comment: Since we're using a left join, those rows in the result of join will have b.id null which are not in the subquery part. It's to simulate the `NOT IN` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Am not a expert in `Mysql` not sure why it is not allowed in `Mysql`. Try something like this

```
DELETE a
FROM   access a
       INNER JOIN (SELECT id
                   FROM   access
                   WHERE  userid = 10
                   ORDER  BY id DESC 
                   LIMIT 100) b
               ON a.id <> b.id
```

**Note :** This might not be efficient as mentioned in comments

Comment: This is going to do cartesian join. Not very efficient.

Comment: @GurV -  That doesn't mean it is not useful.

Comment: @GurV - Also was unable to solve the problem so this gives him a chance at least to solve it